# Microsoft Partner API Network profile no MPN id

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I am writing a connection to the partner center api. I can retrieve all kinds of information. I can verify an mpn id if provided and get an organization. The one call that is failing in an odd way is the mpn profile.

I make the call like this:
GET https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/profiles/mpn HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 
Accept: application/json
MS-RequestId: 76879323-92d1-437e-90dd-c84dbb9f7dec
MS-CorrelationId: cb9f3209-d020-4bf9-871c-e1f1c75348f8
Connection: Keep-Alive

And I get:

{
    "profileType":"MpnProfile",
    "links":{
        "self":{
            "uri":"/profiles/mpn",
            "method":"GET",
            "headers":[]
        }
    },
    "attributes":{
        "objectType":"MpnProfile"
    }
}

I should get the following which includes the mpnID value.

{
    **"mpnId":"",**
    "profileType":"MpnProfile",
    "links":{
        "self":{
            "uri":"/profiles/mpn",
            "method":"GET",
            "headers":[]
        }
    },
    "attributes":{
        "objectType":"MpnProfile"
    }
}

Any insights would be helpful. The only step that was missing in the setup was adding the AAD app key to our partner center. That step has not impacted any other call.

Comment: Did you add the correct authorization token to the request?

Comment: Yes, the odd thing is on the same page using the same token I request the organization and I get that returned as I would expect.

Comment: Hi, Is your problem solved?

Comment: No I have not had time to look at it again.